# Sequelize include (how to structure query)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a query I'm trying to perform based on a one to many relationship. 
As an example there is a model called Users and one called Projects.

Users hasMany Projects

Projects have many types which are stored in a type (enum) column. There are 4 different types that potentially a user may have that I want to load. The catch is I want to include the most recent project record (createdAt column) for all networks that potentially will be there. I have not found a way to structure the query for it to work as an include. I have however found a way to do a raw query which does what I want.

I am looking for a way without having to do a raw query. By doing the raw query I have to map the returned results to users I've returned from the other method, or I have to do a simple include and then trim off all the results that are not the most recent. The latter is fine, but I see this getting slower as a user will have many projects and it will keep growing steadily.

Comment: Have you considered creating a VIEW object in your MySQL database to encapsulate the raw query?

Comment: No I have not. I'm not sure how this would help me with doing what I want with only doing an include within a Sequelize.js query? I can see this being useful, but it still involves me having to parse the data myself and then append it to objects I got from a previous Sequelize query. Perhaps I'm missing your intention of using the VIEW object. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allow serialize a json for anywhere action about a model. Read it, very well

[sequelize-virtual-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-virtual-fields)

```
// define models 
var Person = sequelize.define('Person', { name: Sequelize.STRING });
var Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
name: Sequelize.STRING,
nameWithPerson: {
    type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
    get: function() { return this.name + ' (' + this.Person.name + ')' }
    attributes: [ 'name' ],
    include: [ { model: Person, attributes: [ 'name' ] } ],
    order: [ ['name'], [ Person, 'name' ] ]
}
});

// define associations 
Task.belongsTo(Person);
Person.hasMany(Task);

// activate virtual fields functionality 
sequelize.initVirtualFields();
```

Comment: I did find an alternative solution, but this would also work. Thank you for showing me this package.